# Is std::streampos guaranteed to be unsigned long long?

Tags: c++, file, types, integer, unsigned-long-long-int

Is `std::streampos` guaranteed to be `unsigned long long`?

If not so, how does `std::istream::seekg` work correctly on files larger than 4G?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos:

`std::streampos` is a specialization of the class template

```
template< class State > class fpos;
```

`std::streampos` is typedef'ed to be `std::fpos<std::char_traits<char>::state_type>`

Each object of type `fpos` holds the byte position in the stream (typically as a private member of type `std::streamoff`).

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamoff:

The type `std::streamoff` is a signed integral type of sufficient size to represent the maximum possible file size supported by the operating system. Typically, this is a typedef to `long long`.

To answer your questions...

**Question** Is `std::streampos` guaranteed to be `unsigned long long`?

**Answer** I am sure you meant to find out whether the underlying integral type that holds the position is guaranteed to be `unsigned long long`. In that sense, the real question is whether `std::streamoff` is gueranteed to be `unsigned long long`. The answer to that question is "No", as you can infer from the descriptions above.

**Question** If not so, how does `std::istream::seekg` work correctly on files larger than 4G?

**Answer** If an operating system supports working with files larger than 4G, it's `std::streamoff` is typdef'ed accordingly. Even then, it is most likely going to be a signed integral type. Here's another quote from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamoff.

> A std::streamoff value of -1 is also used to represent error conditions by some of the I/O library functions.

Comment: `streamoff` is definitely signed.  Can you explain the leap from there to making `streampos` signed also?

Comment: @BenVoigt, That was a typo. Thanks for noticing and letting me know :)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not guaranteed to be `unsigned long long`.

Especially with older compilers, it may not work with files larger than 4 GB (and in a few cases it was signed, so it only worked with files up to 2 GB--but when typical hard drives were 20 to 40 megabytes, that probably didn't seem like a major consideration).

Comment: Under what cases should `std::streampos` be signed?

Comment: I think it can only be signed in pre-Standard iostreams