# Creating an error message if user inputs too many characters

Tags: c++, cin, c-strings

I'm pretty new to coding so I apologize if this is trivial. I'm supposed to create an error message when the user enters more characters than my `const int SIZE2` array, which is 20 characters.
My array is called `major`:

```
>cout << "Enter your major: " << endl << endl;
>48         cin.width(SIZE2);
>49         cin.get(major,SIZE2, '\n');
>50         majorLength = strlen(major);
>51         
>52         if(majorLength > SIZE2)
>53         {   
>54             cout << "Too many characters, Enter major again: " << endl;
>55             cin.get(major, SIZE2, '\n');
>56             cin.ignore(100, '\n');
>57          
>58         }
```

It's compiling just fine but skipping over my if-statement.

Comment: once you read the input into something that can only hold 20 characters, checking if it is more than 20 characters does not help anymore. Please provide a [mcve] (only some bits are missing, but details do matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iostream.get()` (here invoked as `cin.get()`) reads an exact number of bytes and then ends. In your case, it will specifically never read more than `SIZE2` bytes into `major`; as a result, `if(majorLength > SIZE2)` will always be false. Also, if you enter too many bytes, `major` will only have the first 20 - the rest are truncated. (FWIW, your code is only matching 19 characters right now.)

Note that you [probably shouldn't try to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631403/7431860) - there's not really a good way to check the length of a stream before you read it, and if you decide to just read it all and *then* check its size, you run the risk of overflowing your buffer - assuming it's fixed size.

You can, however, determine if, after reading, the buffer is empty or not. To determine if there is any more input in the buffer beyond `SIZE2`, you can capture one character with `std::cin.get()` and then examine this character. If the character is `\n`, it means there was no more input in the buffer; if it is not, that means the character buffer had too much input in it. This will also trigger if the input is completely blank.

```cpp
#include <iostream>     

int main () {
  int SIZE2 = 20;

  char str[SIZE2];
  char c;

  std::cin.get (str, SIZE2+1);    // get c-string of 20 chars
  std::cin.get(c); //get last buffer character

  if(c != '\n') {
    std::cout << "bad input!" << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/HospitableWhoppingScientists)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, what would the solution be to avoid this?

Comment: I would recommend using `std::cin` to read directly into a `std::string` variable. You can then check its size. `std::string s; cin >> s; strlen(s);`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use any strings.

Comment: In that case, what is `major`? A char array?

Comment: Yeah its a char array of SIZE2=20

Comment: You need `s.size()`, not `strlen`.

Comment: @jraharris Glad to help! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it addresses your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, this is my first time using this site

Comment: @jraharris Have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) - there's lots of good info there, including [what to do when someone answers your question!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)